# Recursive method construction

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion

Here is my problem:

> Write a recursive method called `binaryToDecimal`. The method should convert a binary string of bits to a base 10 integer. A sample call for an object from our `RecursionExamples` class would be
>
> ```
> answer = example.binaryToDecimal("101111")
> ```
>
> The integer returned would be 47.

I need help to get going with this problem. I know it would be an if-else loop, but how to go about it boggles me. (This is the eclipse environment).

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far.  Also, "I know it would be a for-else loop..." Probably not if it needs to be recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is simple:

1. Think of exit conditions - what is the most atomic string it can process. Bonus points if your methods returns an appropriate error on empty string.
2. Think of how to use your recursive functions. Reese already posted a good solution if you ignore code used to extract lastDigit and restOfString.

Here is a more Java-like pseudo code, without revealing too much:

```
    public int binToDec(String binary)
    {
        if (end_conditions) return int
        int lastDigit = Integer.process
        String restOfString = binary.substring

        return lastDigit + 2* binToDec(restOfString);
    }
```

Comment: appreciate the help, both of you. these recursive methods bug me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it recursivly, consider that the for a binary string, you can convert it to an integer by adding 1 or 0 based on the rightmost number, adding 2 times this function based on the rest of the string.

It would look something like this in pseudocode

```
// input is an integer of 1's and 0's
def f( int binaryString ):
    int lastDigit = binaryString % 10 // Get the last digit
    int restOfString = binaryString / 10 // Remove the last digit

    return lastDigit + (2 * f(restOfString)) // add the last digit to twice f 
                                             // applied to the rest of the string
```

You'll also have to check for when the rest of the string is reduced to nothing as an end condition, but this is the basic logic for the method.

Comment: How so? It is the method you are trying to write, just that it is in pseudocode, not java and you wanted an input string not integer, so either convert it to a number or use the `substring` method of `String` to achieve the same semantic goals.

Comment: i'll post what i come up with shortly

Comment: I can see how this might work, but it suffers from range issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
int binaryToDecimal(String s){
  if (s.isEmpty() || Integer.parseInt(s)==0){  // It's a little weird because the only
    return 0;                                  //    argument is a String.  
  }
  else{
    int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int remainder = number \ 10;
    return lastDigit + 2 * binaryToDecimal(String.valueOf(remainder))
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to point out that providing a working solution to a homework question is bad form.  Then I looked at the code.  :-)